# Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint. Foreign key problem

Tags: mysql, sql, foreign-keys, ddl, create-table

```
create table methodology(
method_id int primary key,
date_added date,
description varchar(1000) character set utf8);

create table text_item(
t_id int primary key,
date_written date,
original_language varchar(2),
description varchar(1000) character set utf8,
foreign key(date_written) references methodology(date_added));
```

I am trying to create a foreign key with the code : `foreign key(date_written) references methodology(date_added));` but it keeps giving me the following error: Error Code: 1215. Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the complete error message you get.

Answer (score 1):

The exact error message is (emphasis is mine):

> Failed to add the foreign key constraint. **Missing index for constraint 'text_item_ibfk_1' in the referenced table 'methodology'**.

This is clear enough. You need an index on the referenced column. Just create it:

```
create index idx_methodology_date_added on methodology(date_added);
```

Then you can create the `text_item` table.

**[Demo on DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=730276a2d9482a49675a882b7ab909dc)**.

Note: while this will technically work, it is quite unclear what the purpose of this relation is; it you want to reference a row in `methodology`, you would better reference its primary key column (`method_id`).